# Reorder vector so no certain items are positioned next to each other

Tags: r

Please consider the following example:

```
[[1]]
[1] 11 12 13 14

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 5

[[5]]
[1] 6

[[6]]
[1] 7

[[7]]
[1] 8

[[8]]
[1] 9

[[9]]
[1] 10

[[10]]
[1] 15

[[11]]
[1] 16

[[12]]
[1] 17
```

In this example, I have 12 unique values in a vector that is 17 elements long. For simplicity, let's say that this vector is:

```
foo_bar <- c("b","b","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","a","a","a","a", "j", "k", "l")
```

The first code block shows the index positions in `foo_bar` of each of the unique values (the letters a–l).

I am attempting to write an algorithm that reorders `foo_bar` so that, for all indices except the final one (index 17 in the `foo_bar` example), position `i` and position `i+1` never contains the same two values. Here's an example of what would be an appropriate outcome:

```
reordered_foo_bar <- c("b","c","b","d","b","e","f","g","h","a","i","a","j","a","k","a", "l")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we identify the indices of the unique values in the vector.

```
indices <- 
  unique(foo_bar) %>% 
  sort() %>% 
  lapply(function(x) which(foo_bar == x))
```

Then we create a position score based on 1) which order the value has when ordered by decreasing frequency and 2) how many previous occurences of this value has occurred, and we add these two values together. However, to ensure that we get a different value inserted between them, we divide 2) by 2. Finally, we order the position scores and reorder `foo_bar` with this new order.

This solution is also robust in case it is not possible to prevent duplicate values next to each other (for example because the values are `c("a","a","b","a")`.

```
out <- 
  lengths(indices) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) 1:x) %>%
  {lapply(len_seq(.), function(x) (unlist(.[x]) + x / 2))} %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  order() %>% 
  {unlist(indices)[.]} %>% 
  foo_bar[.]
```

The output is then:

```
> "a" "b" "a" "c" "b" "d" "a" "e" "b" "f" "a" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l"
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
foo_bar <- c("b","b","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","a","a","a","a", "j", "k", "l")

test == FALSE
while (test == FALSE) {
  new_foo_bar <- sample(foo_bar, size = length(foo_bar), replace = FALSE)
  test <- length(rle(new_foo_bar)$lengths) == length(foo_bar)
}

new_foo_bar
# [1] "f" "a" "g" "b" "h" "d" "j" "c" "e" "i" "a" "b" "k" "a" "l" "a" "b"
```